# http get request is not working in my angular7 project

Tags: javascript, angular7

i tried get request with a header that is Mandatory  to be used but is not working.

i tried testing the API in postman and it's working correctly

here is my service.ts

```
 getUserProfile(){
 let url = '.....'
 const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
 httpHeaders.append('api-client', 'x')
 httpHeaders.append('api-date', 'x');
 const options = {headers: httpHeaders};
 return this.http.get(url, options);
 }
```

here is my app.component.ts

```
 this.networkService.getUserProfile().subscribe((response) => {
 console.log(response)},
(error) => {
  console.log('this is an error ', error)
});
```

i think the problem with the header cause i got null as a value in the console 
[image: check the error here]

error :

this is an error

```
 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 
 "Unknown Error", url: "http://95.......", ok: false, …}
 error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 
 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
  headers: HttpHeaders
  headers: Map(0) {}
  lazyUpdate: null
   normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
   __proto__: Object
  message: "Http failure response for http://95......: 0 Unknown Error"
  name: "HttpErrorResponse"
  ok: false
  status: 0
  statusText: "Unknown Error"
  url: "......"
 __proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Comment: Try using `axios` instead of `http resource`. Visit https://github.com/axios/axios for more axios information.

Comment: please post your error payload

Comment: i posted it, check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

`HttpHeaders.append()` method returns the header instance which should be caught and saved.

```
getUserProfile(){
   let url = '.....'
   const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('api-client', 'x')
   httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('api-date', 'x');
   const options = {headers: httpHeaders};
   return this.http.get(url, options);
 }
```

Comment: Check the api network call in browser's developer tools. Are your headers getting appended in request? And what response are you getting in that network call?

Comment: the header is not appended , i think this is the problem , i got null       
  headers: HttpHeaders
  headers: Map(0) {}
  lazyUpdate: null
   normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
   __proto__: Object

Comment: but the solution which I suggested will append the headers. Have you tried it? `httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('api-client', 'x');`

Comment: From where have you imported `HttpHeaders`? It should be imported from  `@angular/common/http`

Comment: And also `http` should be instance of `HttpClient`.

Comment: import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }